# hive using mysql metastore

Tags: mysql, linux, hadoop, hive

I am successfully run **hive on hadoop using default database**.Now I want to connect Hive through mysql(mysql installed on port 3306).

**Steps:**
1) create hive-site.xml and paste property

```
  <property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>  
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  </property>

  <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hadoop</value>
  </property>

  <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hadoop</value>
  </property>
```

2) Paste connector in hive lib folder.

3) Than check using my mysql but no database created in hive warehouse.

I have no error  but still database not created.Please suggest if have any solution.

**edit**

Error in log file

```
ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin (Log4JLogger.java:error(115)) - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.resources" but it cannot be resolved.
ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin (Log4JLogger.java:error(115)) - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.resources" but it cannot be resolved.
ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin (Log4JLogger.java:error(115)) - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.runtime" but it cannot be resolved.
ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin (Log4JLogger.java:error(115)) - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.runtime" but it cannot be resolved.
ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin (Log4JLogger.java:error(115)) - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.text" but it cannot be resolved.
ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin (Log4JLogger.java:error(115)) - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.text" but it cannot be resolved.
```

Comment: What's there in your log file?Is it still using derby?

Comment: hive.log file(it should be inside /tmp, if you haven't changed it)

Comment: I don't understand please explore which /tmp folder and log files.

Comment: Hive has a log file called hive.log. All the logs get stored in this file right from the time you start Hive. It's default location is /tmp/your_user_name/ directory. If an error occurs that get logged into this file. If you look at it you'll get some idea about the cause of the error. And this /tmp directory is present under the root directory(/) of your machine(in your local filesystem).

Comment: yes , You are right I have some error in log files also edit question. please see.

Comment: Thanks Ruchi. Could you please do this for me?Pastebin(http://pastebin.com/) me your complete log file. It's kinda difficult to find out something just with these lines. The actual problem should be somewhere deep in the log file. Also, if possible for you please switch to chat.

Comment: yahhh i got hive table in mysql. May be problem solve but above four problem still arise in log file.

Comment: Great. I'm sorry, i still need the logs in order to find the root cause.

Comment: plz chk pastebin.com/4pY7YZ3K

Comment: Do you have only this much in your log file?Is your HDFS healthy? Use "hadoop dfsadmin -report" to verify that.

Comment: yess.when use hadoop dfsadmin -report[root@localhost hadoop-1.1.2]# hadoop dfsadmin -report
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Safe mode is ON
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used%: �%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)

Comment: Hmm..NN is not coming out of safemode.Issue this "bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave" and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: yes. I know firstly i am leaving from safe mode bcoz in safe mode hive print exception on shell.

Answer (score 0):

Hive has a limitation:

the database **'hive'** you are using in the following is only to store Hive metadata info in the mysql dbms

```
 1. jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

This ***does not*** mean Hive will use the same name in the HDFS for the data warehouse.
The limitation is that Hive only supports the name **'default'** only as the db name.

JDBC connection string for Hive (this should make things a little clear for you)

```
2. jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default
```

Check the **10000/default** part and compare (1) and (2)

I'm not sure if this has changed as of yet.

Comment: No nothing like that. when we use hive default database then we use jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default . I am using and also created so many database. Now i want to use mysql with hive not hive default database(derby).

Comment: Oops! I saw your point 3, so thought you have this problem.
I think you should elaborate your question a little bit more for everyone to understand you better.